# Using XmlDocument Class to create Xml tags with whitespaces

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmldocument

I'm using the [XmlDocument Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.8) to create a non compliance XML Document with some whitespace inside the XML tags.

The aim is to create a tag like this:

```
<name TYPE="Text">Hey</name>
```

Code:

```
Dim customNodeName = Tag & " TYPE = " & typestr & ""
Dim customNode As XmlNode = doc.CreateNode("element", customNodeName, "")
```

So when I debug my code a

```
 System.Xml.XmlException
 ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20
```

Is thrown.

Is there a possible workaround ?

Comment: If you are using VB I'd use XElement.  I'll post an answer to show you what it looks like using XElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below to test out.  Also, Imports System.Xml :)

```
    ' Just used console app for demo purposes
Sub Main()
    ' Create an XmlDocument to house the stuff
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument

    ' Create your root element
    Dim root As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("root")

    ' Create your 'name' element
    Dim name As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("name")

    ' Set the attribute of 'name' to nothing as your example has.
    name.SetAttribute("Type", "Text")

    ' Set the innerText of your name element as your example has.
    name.InnerText = "Hey"

    ' Append your creations
    root.AppendChild(name)
    doc.AppendChild(root)

    ' This is only here for review
    doc.Save("C:\Temp\Test.xml")
End Sub
```

The code above will yield:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged this VB use XElement.

```
    Dim xe As XElement = <root></root>
    xe.Add(<name TYPE="Text">Hey</name>)
```